# Is there any way to convert Exif Byte Orders of a JPG file from Little-endian to Big-endian?

Tags: metadata, exif, exiftool

I have two files and I'm trying to change my second file from Little-endian to Big-endian,
You can see the following examples here:

First File:

```
$ exiftool FirstFile.JPG | grep "Exif Byte Order"

Exif Byte Order: Big-endian (Motorola, MM)
```

Second File:

```
exiftool SecondFile.JPG | grep "Exif Byte Order"

Exif Byte Order: Little-endian (Intel, II)
```

I tried `exiftool` to change the values but the value didn't change.

```
$ exiftool -ExifByteOrder="Big-endian (Motorola, MM)" SecondFile.JPG 
0 image files updated 
1 image files unchanged
```

I wanna see exactly `Big-endian (Motorola, MM)` when I got the result from `exiftool`.

Any idea?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you think you need to do this?  Because this only changes the byte order in the EXIF data block and does not affect the rest of the jpeg in any way.  Any properly written program that reads the EXIF data will be able to read regardless of whether it's Big-endian or Little-endian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though not directly stated, this is [exiftool FAQ #20](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q20).  Changing the byte order is covered under the "Advanced" section of that FAQ.

You would take the command directly above the "Advanced" section and add change to the `ExifByteOrder` to the command

```
exiftool -exif:all= -tagsfromfile @ -exif:all -unsafe -thumbnailimage -F -ExifByteOrder=Little-endian /path/to/files/
```